# Is using too many HttpClient (HttpClientHandler) considered bad design and how to get around it?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sockets, connection-pooling, dotnet-httpclient

I have read a lot about the socket exhaust problem. In general, this never caused me any problems, I always tried to follow the recommendations as much as possible. But now I have a question. I'm going to make a server application in ASP.net where the user will be able to dynamically instantiate and control instances of a `MyClient` object which should have a unique set of `HttpClient` with an `HttpClientHandler`. It must be unique because certain `CookieContainer` and `Proxy` settings are used. Therefore, they will be created in Runtime, the settings are not known in advance.

`MyClient` is a wrapper with a specific set of Http requests, which has a flexible and deep structure created for specific services. Essentially, it includes:

1. Identity, thanks to the Cookie and Proxy set, which the user sets manually.
2. State control, through an external API, the service determines the session state and other parameters from an external source.
3. Requests to the API of an external service, allowing you to perform actions from the client.
4. Dynamic life cycle. It is instantiated by the user and it is destroyed as it is no longer needed.
   Each user has, although not infinite, but a set of MyClients from 1 to 1000+ instances that will work in parallel. With a life cycle from 5 minutes to months. For clarity, I will give an example code that does not reflect the whole essence, it only serves to understand the approximate implementation.

```
public class MyClient
{
    public HttpClient Client { get; }
    public HttpClientHandler Handler { get;  }
    public int ParameterOfExternalApi1 { get; private set; }
    public object ParameterOfExternalApi2 { get; private set; }

    public MyClient(CookieCollection cookies, IWebProxy proxy)
    {
        BuildClient(cookies, proxy);
        //
    }

    private void BuildClient(CookieCollection cookies, IWebProxy proxy)
    {
        //Building client
        Client = builtClient;
    }

    public async Task MyHttpRequestToExternalAPI()
    {
        await Client.GetAsync("uri");
    }

    public async Task<bool> CheckSession()
    {
        //
    }


    public void Dispose()
    {

    }

}
```

The lifecycle is managed through a pool of clients. If the client is idle, expired, or the user chooses to disable the client, the pool disposes of all unmanaged resources. Again, the code is very approximate, it serves only for clarity.

```
public static class MyPool
{
    private static readonly ConcurrentDictionary<Guid, PooledClient> Pool = new();

    public static MyClient? GetClient(Guid guid)
    {
        return Pool.TryGetValue(guid, out var pooled) ? pooled.Get() : null;
    }

    public static void Dispose(Guid guid)
    {
        //
    }
}


public class PooledClient
{
    private bool _disposed;
    private readonly MyClient _client;

    public PooledClient(MyClient client)
    {
        _client = client;
    }

    public MyClient? Get()
    {
        return _disposed ? null : _client;
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        //
    }

}
```

Actually the question itself is: will not the use of so many HttpClients along with HttpClientHandler create problems, especially on 1000, 5000 or >50000 intances on one server? If it does, is there a solution or workaround?

## upd

Same issue described in https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/35992

Maybe it will clarify my requirenments to the request system.

Comment: Why would an HttpClient live for months? Why would you allow a client of your app to issue 1000 simultaneous outgoing HTTP requests? Why don't you use the web as a UI and create an additional background/Windows service that does the actual calling of the external service, allowing it to gatekeep the abuse your users attempt?

Comment: Both short lived and infinite are bad designs and the proper solutions aren't just *well* documented, they're implemented right into .NET Core's DI. `AddHttpClient` sets up a reusable and periodically recyclable HttpClientHandler pool. Through Polly, you can add retry strategies as well. HttpClient is both thread-safe and *meant* to be reused, so there's no need for multiple instances at all

Comment: Check [Use IHttpClientFactory to implement resilient HTTP requests](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/architecture/microservices/implement-resilient-applications/use-httpclientfactory-to-implement-resilient-http-requests) in the Microservices .NET Architecture book. This isn't specific to microservices by the way.

Comment: Also check the [typed and named clients](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/extensions/httpclient-factory?source=recommendations) scenarios in [IHttpClientFactory for .NET](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/extensions/httpclient-factory?source=recommendations). You can configure HttpClient by the consumer type or name. If you have a `ProductsService` with an `HttpClient` dependency you can use `AddHttpClient<ProductsService>` to both register `ProductsService` *and* configure the HttpClient it uses, along its pooling, recycling and retry strategies

Comment: Thanks for advice. But It is all roundabout my problem. Maybe this thread will clarify my requirenments 
https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/35992 . It is describes my problem well but people there didn't reach any solution. As well I found a really little information about this specific scenario.

Answer (score 1):

> Each user has, although not infinite, but a set of MyClients from 1 to 1000+ instances that will work in parallel. With a life cycle from 5 minutes to months.

That is insane. Seriously. This is the crucial mistake in the design.

The real solution is to not allow such situation. Because as it is, you will exhaust sockets, and there's not much you can do about it. Except for changing the design.

First of all limit the number of client to dozens at most. Globally, not per user. Preferably just one, but depending on your concrete situation (custom TLS handling?) it might not be possible. Secondly lifetime of a month??? What exactly works so long that it needs such huge lifetime? Does  your server run universe simulation? Even if, it is extremely unlikely that you need to keep an open network connection for such a long time.

If there is lots of work to do, then divide the data into pieces, save it to database and schedule workers (meaning process distinct from the server) to pick pieces one by one and process them. And then you can keep the number of clients low, and queued. And you have better control over distribution of tasks.

Also you don't have couple cookie and proxy data with socket (wrappers). Why would you do that? Keep settings separated, and spawn http clients on demand. Put a limit on the number of http clients, and if someone tries to go above put him on a waiting queue.

Comment: This is a project requirement. The user pays for automating actions on an external resource. The number of clients is determined by the requirement of the service for the identity of the Cookie, Header and IP connection to it.

The life cycle is also driven by the requirement for a continuous flow of work until the user loses access or voluntarily disconnects the client.

HttpClientHandler is designed to be pre-configured and does not allow properties to be changed dynamically, so I could not find a solution to dynamically adjust the Headers, Cookies and Proxy settings for each request.

Comment: @achies you know, you can receive a requirement "this project needs to use 100% cpu all the time", it doesn't mean it is reasonable or that you should do it. Secondly, I'm not telling you to modify HttpClientHandler. I'm telling you to divide the work into smaller pieces, schedule it one by one (in a queue) and spawn new clients on demand. So you schedule say 100 thousand jobs, but you have a scheduler that runs only 20 in parallel for example. That way you have 20 clients at each time, not hundred of thousands.

Comment: @achies it's not a project requirement, it's how it was interpreted. HttpClient is reusable, so one instance is enough for 1000 concurrent calls. In fact, all the problems in the question are already solved in .NET itself. There's already a pool, with scheduled recycling (otherwise you wouldn't see DNS changes after eg a failover) *and* retry policies that include exponential backoffs, short-circuiting and more. And you can specify the configuration *per* service

Comment: @achies as for 1000 concurrent, I'll predict a new requirement - don't let clients flood the server by making too many connections. You get *far better* throughput if you *limit* requests to a sustainable rate. After all, a client's requests go out over the same network card, same cable or channel, through the same proxy and router. If you make too many requests the proxies and routers may throttle you before the server does

Comment: @Panagiotis Kanavos
 The problem is not so much with HttpClient as with HttpClientHandler. If 1 user has, say, 30 different sets of Cookies (CookieContainer), Headers and Proxy, which is what the external service requires, and it receives unique data depending on this set of parameters. At the same time, he needs to make 1 request every 10 seconds on each of these sets. I may not understand a little, but I did not see in the .net documentation a similar implementation, where I would specify proxy and cookies sets for each undependent request using HttpClient.

Comment: @achies all you need to make a http request is: server address, http method, http path (all three of these can be encoded as url). Then you need headers (which is just text) and optionally body. You may also need some TLS data, if advanced usage. Either way, all of that is just data that can be stored somewhere (e.g. in memory), read and updated on demand. You do not need to keep connection open just to have this data around. You just create (or if possible: reuse) your http client only when needed, every 10s for this short request/response window, and dispose it afterwards.

Answer (score 0):

Read [IHttpClientFactory](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/architecture/microservices/implement-resilient-applications/use-httpclientfactory-to-implement-resilient-http-requests)

Let the IHttpClientFactory manage each HttpClient's lifetime

> In the above image, a ClientService (used by a controller or client code) uses an HttpClient created by the registered IHttpClientFactory. This factory assigns an HttpMessageHandler from a pool to the HttpClient. The HttpClient can be configured with Polly's policies when registering the IHttpClientFactory in the DI container with the extension method AddHttpClient.

```
public class MyClient
{
    public HttpClient Client { get; }
    public HttpClientHandler Handler { get;  }
    public int ParameterOfExternalApi1 { get; private set; }
    public object ParameterOfExternalApi2 { get; private set; }

    public MyClient(IHttpClientFactory httpClientFactory, CookieCollection cookies, IWebProxy proxy)
    {
        Client = httpClientFactory.CreateClient(); // you can give it a name as well
    }
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

After some research I can say - at the moment, there is no native solution to this issue. Discussions on the github so far are limited only to the consideration of this issue. You will either have to go down a level and reinvent the wheel. Or create a solution that will make the server work as easy as possible, but will not solve the problem completely. (or just switch to python and use `requests`).

Here are links to threads that address this issue:

1. https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/77668
2. https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/23322
3. https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/35992